# In Rails, I am using DateTime.current.in_time_zone(user's timezone"). Do I really need to add utc at the end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, utc

In Rails, I am using DateTime.current.in_time_zone(user's timezone"). Do I really need to add utc at the end?

My code looks t=like this:
**DateTime.current.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").beginning_of_week**

Is this correct or do I need as the below:
DateTime.current.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").beginning_of_week.**utc**

Comment: You may want to consider localizing the dates on the client using JavaScript. This allows you to to use effective caching as the request does not need to be re-proccessed for each different user.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with the date. Using `.utc` at the end will return the time in the selected timezone, converted to the [UTC timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), while the the version without the `.utc` will return the time in the selected timezone.

```
irb(main):001:0> DateTime.current.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").beginning_of_week
Mon, 04 May 2020 00:00:00 PDT -07:00
irb(main):002:0> DateTime.current.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").beginning_of_week.utc
2020-05-04 07:00:00 UTC
```

If you want to show that date to a user in that timezone, you probably want the version without the `.utc`.